# Magento Fatal Error on Running Installation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7, eav-attributes

I am facing below Fatal Error on Magento Running installation,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MagentoEavModelEntityAttributeSourceTable' not found in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('MagentoEavModel...', Array) #1 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('MagentoEavModel...', Array) #2 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php(36): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('MagentoEavModel...', Array) #3 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php(551): Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('MagentoEavModel...') #4 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php(572): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->g in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

Everything was working fine and suddenly this error occur.

When I googled for this error it shows PHP Version incompatibly. But I am using PHP 7.0.33 version and Magento ver. 2.1.8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So are you getting this error while installing Magento in cmd or web interface?

Comment: Not while installing. Website was running earlier and suddenly this error occur while visiting product page from web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions. 
open database and see table : eav_attribute

Now, check the source_model column and you will get MagentoEavModelEntityAttributeSourceTable.

Solution: Replace MagentoEavModelEntityAttributeSourceTable to Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table